# swift во время выполнения цикла for проходит только первая итерация

Tags: многопоточность, swift

Такая задача - делаю табата таймер. Задача  - есть периоды работы и отдыха, которые имеют разные длительности. Во вью контролере это все решается с помощью label, но проблемы начинаются тогда с помощью цикла for перебираем тренировки. А именно - он запускает первое упражнение, все правильно отражается, но пока проходит анимация, он успевает проскочить все остальные итерации. Я понимаю, что вопрос решается скорее всего с помощью работы с потоками, но вот как именно - я так не понял, потому что новичек в этом

класс упражнений и тренировки

```
class Exercise{

var nameOfExercise:String = ""
var isWork:Bool

init(flag:Bool){
    isWork = flag
    }

init(name:String,flag:Bool){
    nameOfExercise = name
    isWork = flag
    }
}


class Training{

var nameOfTraining:String
var exerciseList:[Exercise] = []
var timeOfWork:Int = 30
var timeOfRest:Int = 15

init(name:String) {
    nameOfTraining = name
}

func addExercise(newExercise:Exercise) {
    exerciseList.append(newExercise)
}
}
```

и собственно сам view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var run = 5
var timer:Timer!
var timerIsRun = false

var ex1 = Exercise(name: "run", flag: true)
var ex2 = Exercise(flag: false)
var ex3 = Exercise(name: "push", flag: true)

var training = Training(name: "first")

@IBOutlet  var label:UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = "0"
    training.addExercise(newExercise: ex1)
    training.addExercise(newExercise: ex2)
    training.addExercise(newExercise: ex3)
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func createTimer(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in
        self.changeTimer()})
    timerIsRun = true
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
}

func changeTimer(){
    label.text = String(run)
    self.run -= 1
    if self.run < 0{
        label.text = "0"
        stopTimer()
        timer = nil
    }
}


@IBAction func goTraining(){
    for exercise in training.exerciseList {
        if exercise.isWork == true{
            run = training.timeOfWork
            createTimer()
        } else{
            run = training.timeOfRest
            createTimer()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я переработал ваш код, и вот пример простого таймера с интервалами, можно обойтись одним таймером, просто запускаем отсчет в упражнениях один за другим

```
class Exercise: Equatable {
    var name = ""
    var duration = 3
    
    init(name: String, duration: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.duration = duration
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Exercise, rhs: Exercise) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.duration == rhs.duration
    }
}

enum ExerciseType {
    case work
    case rest
}

class Training {
    
    var name = ""
    var exercises = [Exercise]()
    var timeOfWork = 5
    var timeOfRest = 3
    
    var currentExcercise: Exercise?
    var nextExcersize: Exercise? {
        guard
            let currentIndex = (exercises.firstIndex { $0 == currentExcercise }),
            currentIndex < exercises.count - 1 else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return exercises[currentIndex + 1]
    }
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func addExercise(type: ExerciseType) {
        let excercise = Exercise(name: "no name", duration: type == .work ? timeOfWork : timeOfRest)
        exercises.append(excercise)
    }
    
    func addExercise(name: String, type: ExerciseType) {
        let excercise = Exercise(name: name, duration: type == .work ? timeOfWork : timeOfRest)
        exercises.append(excercise)
    }
}
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer:Timer!
    var timerIsRun = false
    
    let training = Training(name: "first")
    
    @IBOutlet var label:UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        training.addExercise(name: "run", type: .work)
        training.addExercise(type: .rest)
        training.addExercise(name: "push", type: .work)
        
        training.currentExcercise = training.exercises.first
        
        label.text = String(training.currentExcercise!.duration)
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {_ in
            self.updateTimer()
        }
    }
    
    func stopTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    func updateTimer() {
        guard let excercise = training.currentExcercise else {
            // последнее упражнение сделано
            print("done")
            stopTimer()
            return
        }
        
        excercise.duration -= 1
        
        label.text = String(excercise.duration)
        print(excercise.name, excercise.duration)
        
        if excercise.duration == 0 {
            training.currentExcercise = training.nextExcersize
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func goTraining(){
        startTimer()
    }
}
```

Вывод получается такой

```
run 4
run 3
run 2
run 1
run 0
no name 2
no name 1
no name 0
push 4
push 3
push 2
push 1
push 0
done
```